# meaning of 'is to be'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'is to be' in the following sentence and in similar cases?

> We cannot set up in any detail an ideal of character which **is to be** universally applicable.

I wasn't able to find its meaning in OALD.

[UPDATE]

longer context:

> But although we cannot set up in any detail an ideal of character which **is to be** universally applicable—although we cannot say, for instance, that all men ought to be industrious, or self-sacrificing, or fond of music—there are some broad principles which can be used to guide our estimates as to what is possible or desirable.

Comment: Where did you get your example from? It doesn't look very "natural" to me, since the first clause asserts that we ***cannot*** identify such a universally applicable "ideal", but the final clause asserts that such an ideal ***is [destined] to*** [have that attribute]. It's a bit like saying *My car, which **cannot** be repaired, **is to be repaired** today*.. Note that *X is to be Y-ed* means either or both of *X **will be** Y-ed* and *X **is intended / meant** to be Y-ed*. It looks awkward in your context, where normal phrasing is *which **would** be universally applicable* (or ***will be***)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it's from a book written by Bertrand Russell. The whole paragraph: But although we cannot set up in any detail an ideal of character which **is to be** universally applicable—although we cannot say, for instance, that all men ought to be industrious, or self-sacrificing, or fond of music—there are some broad principles which can be used to guide our estimates as to what is possible or desirable.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to claim Russell doesn't know how to write, but it certainly strikes me as a bit clumsy. And it was written [100 years ago](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22industrious,+or+self-sacrificing,+or+fond+of+music%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj41ZWrg4fWAhXHthoKHWG-CgUQpwUIIA&biw=1175&bih=877&dpr=1). But it's really just a slightly odd way of using a construction which would still be perfectly natural today in a context such as *My apples are going to be used to make cider, but yours **are to be** thrown away because they're rotten.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - The construction “***[be + to + verb](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get)***” is a formal construction that is used either a) to give an instruction or command, or b) to tell what is going to happen in the future.

(M-W)

In your sentence   "is to be" could be replaced by "should be".